# java tomcat6: javax.ws missing

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to run TinyFbClient (tiny facebook client) and it needs to import
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder and javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType

i don't have javax.ws package.

what jar file am i missing?

programming using netbeans 6.8
on tomcat 6.0.20

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You need a concrete JAX-WS implementation. Tomcat isn't, it's just a Servlet API implementation. You'll need another appserver which implements JAX-WS as well (e.g. Glassfish), or to add a concrete JAX-WS implementation to your webapp. Glassfish uses [Metro](https://metro.dev.java.net/), which is built on top of [Sun reference JAX-WS implementation](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/). You can download it separately and use on Tomcat as well. If you Google using keywords "[tomcat metro](http://google.com/search?q=tomcat+metro)", you'll find several hints at blogs, for example [this one](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/07/23/metro-tomcat-6x).</strike>

**Update** you need `javax.ws.rs` package, **not** `javax.ws` package only ;) So here's a slight modified answer:

You need a concrete JAX-RS implementation. Tomcat isn't, it's just a Servlet API implementation. You'll need another appserver which implements JAX-RS as well (e.g. Glassfish), or to add a concrete JAX-RS implementation to your webapp. Glassfish uses [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), which is built on top of [Sun reference JAX-RS implementation](https://jsr311.dev.java.net/). You can download it separately and use on Tomcat as well. If you Google using keywords "[tomcat jersey](http://google.com/search?q=tomcat+jersey)", you'll find several hints at blogs, for example [this one](http://syrupsucker.blogspot.com/2008/10/deploying-jersey-in-tomcat-60.html).

Comment: i i downloaded jax-rs latest version and added all of it's jars to my project and still package javax.ws.rs.core.* does not exist!

Comment: err.. i tried to upvote you again (i forgot i already did that) and it removed the upvote and i can't add it now, sorry.

Comment: Then either the `jsr311-api-1.x.x.jar` was missing, or you placed it at the wrong place. It needs to be in `/WEB-INF/lib`. **Edit:** as per the upvote problem, I'll edit my question, then you can upvote again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need JAX-RS on your classpath. [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) is the JAX-RS reference imeplementation.

Googling, as advised by BalusC, gives [this tutorial](http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2009/02/rest-jersey-configuration-on-tomcat.html), which seems like a good one.